# Просмотр собственных панорам прямо в приложении

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Есть ли возможность реализовать просмотр `Photo Sphere` как в `Google Camera` прямо в приложении?

Comment: Конечно же есть, иначе как бы Google это реализовал, если бы возможности не было?

Comment: @metalurgus Вы можете подсказать как это реализовать, может какие сурсы есть?